# How do I repeat a string in jgrasp without using a loop

Tags: java, loops, jgrasp

I cannot find a way to make i repeat in a way where it looks like

```
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Square
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer no greater than 15: ");
        double square= kb.nextDouble();
        double k=1;
        String i= "";
        while (k<square+1)
        {
            k++;
            i=i+"X";
        }
    }
}
```

The final output has to be the letters `X` in a square type formation where if you were to enter 8 for the square variable its 8 across and 8 down.
I knew the outcome of this was going to be wrong i just dont know hot to make it appear like above.
This output looks like

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

if I'm using 8 as square

Comment: Why the prohibition on a loop? Your snippet already has one.

Comment: to be honest i dont really understand what youre asking

Comment: I don't think I can make it much clearer. Your title says 'without using a loop', yet your code snippet includes a `while` loop already.

Comment: ok i understand what youre asking. my problem is getting that outcome, while using the loop. right now the best i can get is

Comment: Use a second loop. Construct a string in the first loop, and print it repeatedly in the second. Or nest one loop inside another and print characters with the inner loop, lines with the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second loop. Construct a string in the first loop, and print it repeatedly in the second. Or nest one loop inside another and print characters with the inner loop, lines with the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is that you are running a while loop and increment the value of k every iteration until it reaches the input value.

The problem with this is that the first iteration k will be 1 for the first iteration, which means it will only print out 1 X. Next iteration it will only print out 2 X, again because you are increment k by 1 every time. The while loop based on k. Thats how you have it set up.

One way you could do this would be use 2 nested loops. 
if input = 8,

```
  for(int i = 0; i<input; i++){
     System.out.println();        // <----- This just jumps to next line
      for(int k = 0; k<input; k++){
         System.out.print("X");

      }     
  }
```

output

XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX